# Regex [data parsley pattern] Allow special characters

Tags: javascript, regex, parsley.js

apologies my regex skills are lacking.

I'm using parsleyjs & I have this rule:

```
export const PASSWORD_RULE5 = /[\[\]@$!%*?&£€^(){}:"|<>/]{1}/;
```

This works.  The rule is applied, if one of those characters does not appear in the password it highlights and warns them they need to add a special character.

the problem is the Input has a **data_parsley_pattern**:

```
data_parsley_pattern = "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&£€^(){}:"|<>])[A-Za-z\\d!$%@#£€*?&]{8,}$"
```

This allows a password with

- At least 8 characters
- At least 1 uppercase char
- At least 1 lowercase char
- At least 1 numeric
- At least 1 special character

If they enter a `^` in their password, it no longer highlights, but the data_parsley_pattern still fails.

No matter what I try I cannot get this to work.

I've tried adding the new allowed special characters here & also tried escaping them, but the rule still fails.

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&**£€^(){}:"|<>/**])[A-Za-z\\d!$%@#£€*?&]{8,}$
```

Or

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&**£€\\^\\(\\)\\{\\}\\:\"\|\\<\\>\\/**])[A-Za-z\\d!$%@#£€*?&]{8,}$
```

Do I need to treat these characters differently?

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: But while `^` is allowed in the positive lookahead, it is not within the character class right after that. So it makes perfect sense it fails. A password entered with a `^` fails on your character class that does **not** include that character, meaning it is not allowed. Well, that's how I read your question. Is this simply a typo?

Comment: This works https://regex101.com/r/JxnyPm/1

Comment: Thank you both so much.  I managed to resolve this with your comments!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to comments from @JvdV, I realised I was missing out my special characters in an important part of the regex.

Thanks To @Pradeep, the tool you provided in the comment is a massive help when testing Regex.

Another issue I had was that I am using ASP.Net MVC and an @Html.PasswordFor therefore the escape characters are slightly different.

Here's the solution for my issue above:

**data_parsley_pattern = "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[\\\"@$!%*?&£€^(){}:|<>/])[A-Za-z\d!$%@#£€*?&^(){}\\\":|<>/]{8,}$"**